# Node Js - Validation Issue

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, joi

While validating user it always stucks on name validation and send response "name" is required and I am sending the name in request body but still getting this error. I attaching the images link for all of you to understand my issue clearly. Thankyou
[user.js image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYKI.png)  [register.js image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuICx.png)  [server.js image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJyI6.png)  [postman respone image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SNUo.png)

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Questions need to stand on their own. Please include text, not links to images of text. Please keep in mind that we cannot see the data being sent unless you include it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking correct to me, but while sending the post request you're not including the "admin" property which is required in both mongoose and Joi schemas.